# How to change in Javascript the Button Name with a prompt

Tags: javascript

I try to change the name of my button by a prompt.

The goal is, if I enter in the prompt "summer", the button should get the name "summer". If not, what you have entered should be displayed as a string.

I have this code so far.

This code is in the Head

```js
var name = prompt("Geben Sie die Zeichenkette ein:");
if (name == "Sommer") {
  document.getElementById("input").value = "Sommer";
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <input id="input" type="button" name="" value="Hallo"></input>
</div>
```

everything was supposed to work, right?

Comment: Do not put Javascript in the `head`: you never should, for whatever reason.

Comment: @cs1349459 Okey, I moved it to the Body. Have still the question with the name change :(

Answer (score 0):

This is all you have to do:

```js
var name = prompt("Geben Sie die Zeichenkette ein:");
if (name == "Summer") {
  document.getElementById("input").name = "Summer";
} else {
document.getElementById("input").value = name;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <input id="input" type="button" name="" value="Hallo"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = prompt("Geben Sie die Zeichenkette ein:");
if (name =='summer'){
    document.getElementById("input").value = name;
}else{
    document.getElementById("string").innerHTML = name;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="input" type="button" name="" value="Hallo">
</div>
<div id='string'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you just think too much.

Of course I just had to add my script at the end.